# Mouse click results in unexpected behavior using wxPython & wx.Panel

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, mouseevent

I am writing an application in which the following steps are intended to be executed:
1 - user clicks in blue area (a wx.Panel) and a white circle appears;
2 - user clicks Select Start button;
3 - user clicks in the white circle and it changes to green (by drawing a green circle over the white one)
The problem is that when step 3 is executed the green circle does not appear where the mouse is clicked. For example, clicking in the blue area registers a point at (223, 486). After clicking the Select Start button and then clicking in the white circle a point registers at (211, 464), and a green circle appears outside the white circle. I don’t understand why this is happening and would appreciate any help in resolving the problem.
Using python 2.7 with wxPython 3.0.3.0 on MacOs

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (820,900))
        
        self.startSelected = False
        self.radius = 10
        
        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(800,800))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,200))
        
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onMouseDown)
        
        self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(0,0)   
        
        self.startBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label = 'Select Start')
        self.startBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.selectStart)
    
        self.gbs.Add(self.panel, span = (1,4), pos=(1,1),flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.gbs.Add(self.startBtn, pos=(2,1))

        self.SetSizer(self.gbs)
        
    def onMouseDown(self, e):
        pt = e.GetPosition()
        print pt.x, pt.y
        
        if e.LeftDown():
            if self.startSelected:

                color = wx.Colour(0,255,0)
                self.paint(pt, color)

            else:
                color = wx.Colour(255,255,255)
                self.paint(pt, color)                 
            
    def paint(self, pt, color):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        b = wx.Brush(color)
        dc.SetBrush(b)
        dc.DrawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, self.radius)
        
    def selectStart(self, e):
        self.startSelected = True
        
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None, 'Test')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wx.ClientDC` is relative to the object passed to it. As coded in the paint method, `dc = wx.ClientDC(self)`, `self` is the `wx.Frame`. Since drawing is done on the `wx.Panel`, `dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)` should be used. This results in the expected behavior.